# How can I run permanently my php chat socket app on Ubuntu or Debian sever?

Tags: php, sockets, server, debian, chat

I have a chat socket app in php, and I'd like to run not just on my local computer, but also on a webserver. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

php -f library/filename.php

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

What your answer is missing is how to keep it going, how to get it started on system reboot, how to restart it in case it stops for some reason, etc.

Depending on your distribution, you may be able to use `screen` or a similar utility to keep it alive.  Or, you can write a systemd service file and let systemd manage keeping it going.